# How to exit from emacs shell

Tags: emacs, debian

I gave M-x shell to get Linux shell. How to go back to the current document from there

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can switch the buffer back to the one you were at previously by: `C-x b` and `enter`

Or if you're done with the shell, you can type `exit` to stop the shell and kill the buffer by: `C-x k`

Answer (score 1):

You can run C-x b to switch to previous buffer. You can also do C-x C-b and switch to whichever buffer you need.  Read tutorial with C-h t  and see the Buffers section.